# iTunes Connect Edit Metadata broken?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is anyone else experiencing this issue when inputting new metadata for an app? Any text I put in the metadata section is being crammed together regardless of spacing. So two seperate paragraphs below become one together.

> This is paragraph one.
>
> And this is paragraph two.

...

> This is paragraph one. And this is paragraph two.

Comment: Maybe try a different web browser?

Comment: @Dominik Looks like I get the same issue on both Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Then I really don't know :/ It doesn't happen to me.

Comment: Weird. It happens to me on both the update section of another game and anywhere in the metadata on a new game. Happens on either of those browsers and even after I restarted everything :|